# javadocs attached on project build path, but it isn't found by eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Until now i haven't got problems with eclipse,but i can't figure out how to resolve this issue

i created a simple project:
[image]

i can't see the `javadocs` attached like:

[image]

in my project build path i imported the `JRE`

[image]

**UPDATE**

(.log file) inside .metadata folder:

```
Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [Unknown javadoc format for String {key=Ljava/lang/String;} [in String.class [in java.lang [in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]]]]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavadocContents.getTypeDoc(JavadocContents.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BinaryType.getAttachedJavadoc(BinaryType.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.javadoc.JavadocContentAccess2.getHTMLContent(JavadocContentAccess2.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.getHoverInfo(JavadocHover.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.internalGetHoverInfo(JavadocHover.java:612)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.getHoverInfo2(JavadocHover.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:166)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 1009 2014-11-10 16:40:25.042
!MESSAGE Unknown javadoc format for String {key=Ljava/lang/String;} [in String.class [in java.lang [in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]]]
```

i don't understand what's wrong, i didn't make any changes, do i have to reinstall eclipse?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for a more detailed error.

Comment: i'll post it, wait a bit.

Comment: @greg-449 there are a lot of informations, what kind of those i have to catch?

Comment: @greg-449 i updated the question, i understand that it can't reach the String but, how i can resolve?

Comment: I think using a JDK instead of a JRE would solve the problem.

Comment: i' m using this JRE since one year no problem with it, i' ll try the JDK.

Comment: This is happening to me, too.